# Como solucionar esse "ValueError" no Python 3?

Tags: python

estou tendo dificuldade de solucionar esse erro:

*ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)*

Esse é meu código:

```
def func(array, n):
    m = len(array)
    soma = 0
    saldo = []
    res = 0
    bool = False

    saldo = [0 for i in range(n+1)]


    for i in range(m):
        x, v, y = [x for x in range(n)] # **O erro está nessa linha**
        saldo[x] += v
        saldo[y] += v
        soma += v

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if saldo[i] > 0:
            #res.append(saldo[i]) 
            res += saldo[i]
        elif saldo[i] < 0:
            #res.append(-saldo[i]) 
            res += -saldo[i]



    if res == soma:
        bool = False
    else:
        bool = True


    return bool, res
        
print(func([[3,1,10],[2,1,40],[2,4,30],[2,4,20]], 4))
```

Agradeço desde já ;)

Comment: Você quatro elementos na lista para desembalar e apenas três variáveis para receber esses elementos. Um elemento fica sobrando.

Comment: Talvez seja melhor explicar o que o código deveria fazer (qual deveria ser o resultado: dado os valores A e B, deveria retornar X eY, etc). De repente a solução nem precisa do unpacking...

Answer (score 0):

O seu 'n' está valendo 4, e ,eu fiz um teste, quando você coloca '...for x in range(n)' ou seja '...for x in range(4)', o programa entende que o começo é 0, então ele conta, 0, 1 ,2 ,3. que são 4 elementos. Para resolver é só colocar '...for x in range(1, n)'. espero que ajude. =)